# Bind two data in a textbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I am building an application for Windows Phone 7 where i need to display data of two fields in a single textblock and it should be separated by comma. I tried it using the following xaml code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=city_name}"> "{Binding Path = state}"
Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
```

It didnt work. Please help to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Unfortunately WP7 doesn't support `MultiBinding`.

You could use a similar functionality with a `ValueConverter`. Anyway, a much easier way would be to use several `TextBlocks`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding city_name}" />
    <TextBlock Text=", " />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding state}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Old (wrong) answer:

<strike>You can do this with a `MultiBinding` which can have a `StringFormat`:</strike>

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
            <Binding Path="city_name" />
            <Binding Path="state" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I am getting an error:    The type 'MultiBinding' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: I'm sorry, WP7 doesn't seem to support MultiBinding. I'll change the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class that handle the two objects and make a public property that returns both concatenated. You can bind your control to that property.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to use Run element inside the TextBlock. See this: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/05/12/silverlight-xaml-primer-15-enhancing-textblock-with-runs-and-linebreaks.aspx